# Kink in Dispersion Relationship due to Electron Phonon Coupling

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, electrons, superconductivity, phonons

How can I start from a Hamiltonian with electron-phonon coupling and show that a kink should show up in the energy dispersion relationship?

In a brief communication called ["Universal Nodal Fermi Velocity"](https://www.nature.com/articles/423398a) there is a graph showing a kink in data collected from Angle Resolved Photo-Emission Spectrometry. After looking around a bit I found a [review](https://journals.aps.org/rmp/abstract/10.1103/RevModPhys.93.025006) that convinced me that this is due to electron-phonon coupling and am now trying to convince myself with the math.